# Cloth still going through with self collisions on

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, cloth-simulation, blend-files, collision

I'm trying to add cloth simulation a skirt that has 2 combined meshes in it, so I needed to use self collision so it wouldn't collide, but it still ends up colliding together, and then it ruins the other part of the skirt. I have tried to play with the settings so many times but nothing seems to be working. Is this an actual problem or do I just have to keep experimenting with settings? If so, could someone please suggest me some settings? Some pictures:

An example of settings I tried before:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/siLJY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ3dj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQAjT.png

What's happening (if you don't understand, there's a black part underneath it):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBGwW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUCnN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByJch.png

Also, I'm kind of curious, what is Impulsive Clamping and is it something I should add?

I'd also like to point out there's a part near the beginning (around frame 290-300) where the model bends and it kind of messes up. If there's any way to fix that too please let me know. I'm putting the blend file in here too just in case:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U7F6USSXd50im13p6KiInHf8Pm1TkL5Y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the quality steps to 10 under the tab "Physics".

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helped, but at one point the models kneels down (like what I said before, except that got fixed because it wasn't really down), and now it actually ruins everything, it crumbles it and doesn't make it fall back down. How can I fix this?

Comment: At what frame does this happen?

Comment: Frame 2069 onwards.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that there's only collision on the legs, so I don't know if I should add collision on her upper body or..

Comment: yes you should definitely!

Comment: Do you think it would fix it? I tried it before but I ended up doing it on her outfit too which messed it up completely, I will try to update in the morning.

Comment: if it doesn't, play around with quality settings - also in the collision tab until it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128331/discussion-between-uvennaa-and-chris).